# "Awebrowser" Pop Up Is Blocking My Internet Access With Ubuntu

Tags: internet, browser

I have a Dell netbook with Ubuntu loaded onto it.  When I try to access the Internet, a dialog box pops up that says:

> Awebrowser cannot be located.

or something of that nature.

How can I get rid of this that is blocking me from accessing the Internet?

Comment: Are you clicking an icon? how are you "accessing" the internet?

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate, that either there is no sensible webbrowser installed at all, or that the standard browser is set to nonexisting program named ... awebrowser (never heard of it).

See in the software center if firefor or chromium ist installed, install it if needed (Firefox should be the dafault webbrowser in ubuntu)

If the problem persists, run `sudo update-alternatives x-www-browser /usr/bin/firefox` in a terminal, this registers firefox as the daefault web browser for your system.